# Chrome Extension - tab creation / remove issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension that creates a new tab, loads a page, retrieve the source code and closes the tab. It's my first Chrome Extension.

So far creating the tab, retrieving the source code and closing works but something I can't explain is happening in the flow that causes repetitions.

I'm calling the following function in a FOR loop:

```
function chromeTabsCreateAsync(createProperties) 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        {
            console.log('tab start');
            chrome.tabs.create(createProperties, tab => 
                {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) 
                        {
                            reject(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError));
                        } 
                    else 
                        {

                        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
                        function onUpdated(updatedTabId, details) 
                            {
                                    console.log(details.status+' '+tab.id);
                                    if (details.status == 'complete') 
                                        {

                                            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, 
                                                {
                                                    file: 'test.js',

                                                }, function(results) 
                                                {

                                                    var source = results[0];

                                                    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id); 
                                                    resolve(source);
                                                });

                                        }
                            }
                        }

                });
            console.log('tab end'); 
        });
}
```

The properties contain:
url: some url
active: false

I have voluntarily added console.log everywhere to show what is happening.

Here is the output I see in my console:

First iteration:

```
tab start
tab end
loading 16
undefined 16
complete 16
```

=> so far, everything is ok

Second iteration:

```
tab start
tab end
loading 16
loading 18
undefined 16
undefined 18
undefined 16
undefined 18
complete 16
complete 18
```

=> uh? what is 16 doing here, the tab was already closed during the first iteration

Third iteration:

```
tab start
tab end
loading 16
loading 18
loading 20
undefined 16
undefined 18
undefined 20
undefined 16
undefined 18
undefined 20
complete 16
complete 18
complete 20
```

=> and it goes on like this, each iteration takes the tab id from the previous ones while those tabs have been closed.

Of course because the id doesn't exist anymore, I get an error:

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: No tab with id: 16. at onUpdated

Do you have any idea why those iterations re-use previous ids ?

thanks

Laurent

Comment: You have many chrome.tabs.onUpdated concurrently active so they all get called and repeatedly invoke executeScript. In this particular case you don't need onUpdated at all. Simply call executeScript in tabs.create's callback - it'll run the script when the tab is loaded, see the documentation.

Comment: Just one more detail, I'm calling this function with "await" to make sure it gives me the source code before doing anything else: source = await chromeTabsCreateAsync({ url: search_url, active: false });

Comment: Hello wOxxOm, wow, that was quick and that solves the issue! Thanks a lot. How can I credit you for the solution? I can't flag a comment as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was provided by wOxxOm (see first comment)